# c# WebClient использование нескольких сетевых адаптеров

Tags: c#

Есть ли в C# возможность загрузки файлов с сайтов через два сетевых адаптера. 
WebClient не дает такой возможности.

Comment: Вы хотите делить между адаптерами нагрузку одного файла? Или просто загрузка двух файлов через два разных адаптера одновременно вас тоже устроит? Т.е. вы ищете именно балансировку? или просто возможность выбрать адаптер при скачивании каждого из файлов?

Comment: @PashaPash, ответ Вы знаете, обсуждали его в комментариях удаленного мной ответа. Почему не отвечаете и вопрос висит уже два часа без ответа? Простое любопытство.

Comment: Нужно скачивать файлы с сайта в нескольких потоках и через два и более сетевых адаптера

Comment: @Alexis не знал, ответ ли это, т.к. не знал - один здоровый файл топикастер качает (тогда не ответ) или несколько (тогда да, BindIPEndPointDelegate - ответ, но его стоит проверить кодом и оформить, а времени пока не нашлось :( ).  Если у вас есть возможность оформить - я совсем не против если вы его запостите.

Comment: @PashaPash, к сожалению только увидел Ваш комментарий( и тоже весь в работе(( ТС, покопай в сторону ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate, если ничего не получится - уже напиши, так же посмотри ответ на мой аналогичный вопрос, но только для TcpClient: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542414/6545