# Нужен пример кода для одновременных приема и отправки данных через два сетевых интерфейса при помощи TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net

Прошу привести пример кода для одновременных приема и отправки данных через два сетевых интерфейса при помощи `TcpClient`.

Мотивация: мне нужно осуществлять балансировку запросов через несколько сетевых интерфейсов. Для `WebClient` есть опция `ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate`, но я не нашёл похожей опции для `TcpClient`.

Comment: Теперь то что не так? По аналогии с опцией ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate для WebClient - прошу привести аналог для TcpClient. Это нужно для программной балансировки запросов через два сетевых интерфейса без использования сторонних средств.

Comment: Я не прошу приводить огромный пример, нужны только ключевые аспекты, такие как одновременная работа объектов TcpClent-а с двумя сетевыми интерфейсами.

Comment: Возможно, мотивацию вопроса стоит переместить из комментария в сам вопрос.

Comment: @VladD, мне вот интересно - почему люди, ничего не понимающие в шарпе судя по статистике - закрыли вопрос? Это новая волна такая - влезть туда, в чем совершенно не разбираешься?)))

Comment: @VladD, причем почти у всех основное направление даже не Windows, а Linux....

Comment: @VladD, я предлагал правку вопроса, ее отклонили. А ТС видимо потерял надежду получить ответ, либо просто не видит того безобразия - которое тут творится...

Comment: @Align: Для этого есть кнопка «переоткрыть». Проголосовал за переоткрытие.

Comment: @VladD, к сожалению моя репутация не позволяет этого сделать, так бы последовал Вашему примеру.

Comment: @Align: Брошу в чат, надеюсь, там найдутся желающие переоткрыть вопрос. Кроме того, я сделал уточняющую правку, так что вопрос попадёт в очередь на переоткрытие.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю, думаю это будет честно по отношению к ТС. Мне вот просто интересно - в данном случае на закрытие вопроса повлиял стадный инстинкт? Почему люди, которые не разбираются в вопросе - закрывают его? Им за это репутацию начисляют? Либо просто стремятся закрыть сложные вопросы без ответа, оставив только простые вопросы с ответами?

Comment: @Align: Вот, переоткрыли!

Comment: @VladD, @ Align - вот теперь отвечайте :-)

Comment: @Grundy, полагаю что нету такой возможности, но не уверен. Но согласитесь - ответ "невозможно в текущей реализации" и "MS - индусы, совершили тотальную ошибку, снабдив WebClient данной возможностью, но забыли про фундаментальный TcpClient" - тоже ответ. Но повторюсь, я не уверен, поэтому не буду спешить и писать это. Именно поэтому я назвал вопрос сложным и мне самому интересен точный ответ на него.

Comment: @Grundy: Готово.

Comment: @VladD, подождем автора :-)

Comment: @Align@VladD - спасибо за помощь, спасибо что не дали закрыть вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мне кажется, вам подойдёт [конструктор `TcpClient` с `IPEndPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx).

Из примера в документации:

```
var ips = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;
var localEndPoints = ips.Select(ip => new IPEndPoint(ip, port: 0));
// как-то отфильтровать список
var tcpClients = localEndPoints.Select(endPoint => new TcpClient(endPoint)).ToList();
```

Как найти, какие из интерфейсов относятся к внешнему соединению, обсуждается [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6803073/276994). (Ну или можно попробовать подсоединиться к [google.com](http://www.google.com) для теста, наверное.)

Comment: А есть ли решение для HttpClient? чтобы одновременно через 2 интерфейса работать?

Comment: @vitidev: Для `HttpClient` не нашёл.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю, вариант рабочий, проверил только что. Кому интересно могу пример для проверки выложить, но думаю тут люди сами все это могут написать.

Comment: @Alexis: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!